# Error publishing git repo on ubuntu

Tags: git, publish, redmine

I am trying to publish a repository on an Ubuntu virtual machine (A turnkeylinux redmine appliance).

On the machine there are other git repos correctly working.

- I have created a new project, at `/my/path/to/proj/`
- run `git init`
- commit a test file
- run `touch /my/path/to/proj/.git/git-daemon-export-ok`
- run `chmod -x /my/path/to/proj/.git/git-daemon-export-ok`
- tried clone `git::/my_server/git/proj/.git` It says

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Any clues? Keep in mind that other git repos run just fine on the same VM

Should the repo be in the same place as the other working repos? How do I tell git daemon to map between `git::/my_server/git/proj/.git` and `/my/path/to/proj/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `git-daemon` running on this system? Note in particular arguments given to `--base-path`, `--interpolated-path`, `--user-path` or directories specifically listed on the command line. Is `/my/path/to/proj` in one of those places (or in the directory where `git-daemon` is started from)?